# Samsung Smart Tv - SEF vs PNaCL

Tags: javascript, c++, native, samsung-smart-tv

I am trying to understand if I can develop Samsung Smart Tv *Native* application with lower level api than PNaCL, which is I suspect just javascript via pepper.js...

Samsung do not provide too much information about how exactly they implement their NaCL "native" development. PNaCL is the only somewhat documented way, but I found this "SEF plugin" that is supposed to connect the JS to "low level c++ modules" as says the docs, without too much explanation.

Probably, there's no SEF dev platform. Probably .. just checking that I did not get it wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PNaCl is just like module that can be executed in C/C++ Runtime which resulting greater performance than javascript that running over web runtime.

Not sure about the exact answer, but this is my understanding. Because of the SEF is more likely system object interface then it should compiled with firmware. And yes, i agree with you the SEF is "lower" than the PNaCl but i think that's impossible for us to create our own SEF plugin except Samsung releasing the source code and method to flash the firmware like android device.

```
System Runtime     | <==> Sandboxed Runtime <==> PNaCl
                   |                               /\
                   |                               ||
                   |                               \/
           [SEF Object] <======================> Web Runtime <==> Javascript
```